# CakePHP hasMany relationship access question

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 3 models that are related:

Folders
Files
Revisions

Folders have many Files. Files have many revision. Files have one folder. Revisions have one file.

I've setup all my relationships and everything is getting created right in the database. I am trying to edit the scaffolded HTML and have a really basic question: how do I access the revision numbers from the folders view?

That is, I want to print out a table that lists all the files in a folder and all the revisions for each of those files. I am a CakePHP newbie, and I know this is a simple thing, but I'm just not getting it!

I read this page: http://book.cakephp.org/view/81/belongsTo, which instructed me to do something like $this->Profile->find(), but I don't understand where this goes (controller? model? how does this ultimately show up in the view.ctp file?)

Answer (score 1):

To approach your goal only two relationships are required

```
Folder hasMany File
File hasMany Revision
```

The other two you set are not correct.Files should `beLongsTo` folders and revisions `beLongsTo` files.If you set all relationships correctly,you will get the data you need simply using

`$this->Folder->find('all');`